# responsive web design with scaling image with always fully visible page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to build a web page that essentially consists of two elements: an area where an image is shown and an area where text is shown.

The content should always be totally visible regardless of the page size, without anything outside, without the need for scrolling.

There should be two layouts:

1. wide (for page widths > 800px): The image area on the left (75% of the page width), the text area on the right (20% of the page width), both 95% of the page height.
2. narrow: The image area on top (75% of the page height), the text area below (20% of the page height), both 95% of the page width.

The original image can have different widths and heights, the ratio can be different, but when displayed it should always fit with its maximum possible size into the image area, centered (for instance an image of 1000x500px should be 800x400px in a 800x800px div, 200px from upper border).

Is there a responsive solution without fixed or explicit pixel amounts?

If not, what is the best solution?

Comment: There are couple solutions, but you need to show us what have you tried, you need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a CSS media query and some tricks to center your images vertically and horizontally.
Like this :

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.image-container {
  width: 75%;
  height: 95%;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.image-container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.text-container {
  width: 20%;
  height: 95%;
  background: green;
  float: right;
}

@media screen and ( max-width: 800px ) {
  .image-container {
    float: none;
    width: 95%;
    height: 75%;
  }
 
  .text-container {
    float: none;
    width: 95%;
    height: 20%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="http://sport-nc.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/India_Surf_Tours_-_17__1_.jpg"/>
  </div>
  <div class="text-container"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But there was a slight misunderstanding: The image should always be shown in full, no part missing, so an image of 1000x500 will be 800x400 in a 800x800 div.

Comment: Now, I think this is what you are looking for. Is it ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Thank you very much for your help! I would upvote your answer, but I don't have enough points.